# Inserting a data in mysql using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Hi guys I have Table "Item" that have a "Name" field.
I am trying to insert a data but I am getting an error. Please see my below code for further information.

item.php

```
class Item {

public function create(){
  $attributes = $this->attributes();
  $pair = array();

  foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
    $pair[] = "'{$key}'=>{$value}";
  }

  $bind = ":" . implode(", :",array_keys($attributes));
  $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name
       . " (" . join(",",array_keys($attributes)) . " ) VALUES "
       . " ( " . $bind . " )";

  $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute($pair);
  if($result){
    return $result;
  } else {
    $error = $this->database->errorInfo();
  return $error;
  }
}

}
```

index.php

```
<?php
   $item->name = "Sample Name";
   $item->create();
?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in PATH on line 62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$pair` array looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => "'foo'=>bar"
    1 => ...
)
```

Which is nonsense. The `execute()` method expects an array with named keys, not numeric keys with garbage values. Get rid of the `$pair` thing entirely and pass `$attributes` to `execute()` instead.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Just get rid of anything related to `$pair` and call `$stmt->execute($attributes)`.

Comment: I was solving that for 2 hours already. Thanks.
It is the same for UPDATE right? :)

Answer (score 1):

`$pair` part is wrong... You should check out [PDOStatement::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) manuals.

Your `$pair` array looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "'key'=>value"
}
```

but it should be:

```
array(1) {
  [":key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

Find the solution yourself :)